# How do I (manually) install the Java plugin in Firefox 4

Tags: firefox, java

I'm trying to manually install the Java plugin for [Firefox 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_4) on Mac OS X v10.9 (Mavericks) (I got Firefox 4 from the PPA), but it seems the [usual instructions](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#enable)  don't work. I've tried doing both

```
cd ~/.mozilla/plugins
ln -s $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so .
```

and

```
cd /usr/lib/firefox
ln -s $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so .
```

but I still get the "missing plugin" warning in Firefox. It used to work fine for Firefox 3.6. Also, after doing the first above, Chromium is able to pick up the Java plugin without problems. In case it makes any difference I'm running Oracle's "vanilla" JDK, ***not*** the Ubuntu `sun-java-6-bin` package.

Comment: Are you using 32-bit Ubuntu or 64-bit version? Is the JAVA_HOME environment variable set to the actual location of the Java installation?

Comment: 32bit ubuntu, JAVA_HOME set and pointing to the JDK install directory, I've even fixed the alternatives system.

Comment: is `$JAVA_HOME` set? (does `echo $JAVA_HOME` give a path to the JRE path?)

Comment: yup, JAVA_HOME is set and points to /usr/local/java which is a symlink to the jdk.

Answer (score 4):

If you run the Oracle Java standalone installer (`.bin` file), it will just extract the java directory from the archive. It will not create the environment variable JAVA_HOME. It is best if you extract the java archive to a folder such as `/usr/java`.

Next, find the folder where Firefox is installed. It will have a directory named `plugins` there. In this directory, create a soft link to the file `libnpjp2.so`.

On my computer, I did with these commands. It will be different in yours.

```
cd /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.3/plugins
sudo ln -s /usr/java/jre1.6.0_20/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so  .
```

After doing this, you can type `about:plugins` in Firefox to check the plugin availability in the browser.

Comment: +1 Great! This worked like a charm for me on firefox 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this website to get the latest version of Java and the Java plugin working:

[Easy Linux Tips: Install Java](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java)

Comment: Instructions on that page boil down to the usual "create a symlink somewhere in your home". Still doesn't work on firefox4.