# Java plugin in Firefox

Tags: firefox, java

Having trouble getting Java to work with Firefox (version 22), I have followed the advice in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48782/how-do-i-manually-install-the-java-plugin-in-firefox4) and on the official Java site, but nothing seems to work.

I have the latest Java (1.7.0_25) in `/opt/java` and have set a symlink in `/usr/libs/mozilla/plugins` for the `libnpjp2.so` file. I can see the file in the terminal and Java runs fine. However, Firefox shows nothing in `about:plugins`. I have also run

```
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jre1.7.0_05/bin/java"
```

to be on the safe side. I know there are multiple plugin directories such as `/usr/lib/firefox/plugins` and `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins`, but all my current plugins show they are located in `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` when viewing the `about:plugins` page.

Where do I go next?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not to use a manual installation. In this case you have to manually update Java as well. There is a nice workaround with a automatic update function:

https://askubuntu.com/a/368529/153278