# Update java plug-in

Tags: java, plugins

Chrome and Firefox are using java plug-in 1.7.0_25, which is automatically disabled because it is not a safe version (I should install plug-in 1.7.2_45). The problem is that it doesn't matter what I do, Chrome and Firefox keep pointing to the wrong version.

How should I proceed in order to use the correct plug-in, I really need it to access many important sites.

Comment: Could you detail how you installed Java?

Comment: Give a try to [this](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-java-plugin-to-view-interactive-content) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491322/how-to-add-java-plugin-for-firefox-on-linux) link. Hope you would get more help from these links.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the current Java version and all its configuration files:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge icedtea-7-plugin
   ```
2. Get the latest one from Java website [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en) as the one in Ubuntu Repositories is 1.7.0_25.
3. Install it using these instructions:

   - Change to the directory in which you want to install.

     ```
     cd /directory/path/name
     ```

   For example, to install the software in the /usr/java/ directory, Type:
   `cd /usr/java/`

   Note about root access: To install Java in a system-wide location such as /usr/local, you must login as the root user to gain the necessary permissions. If you do not have root access, install the Java in your home directory or a sub directory for which you have write permissions

   - Move the .tar.gz archive binary to the current directory. (Use `sudo` if you're moving to a system location.)
   - Unpack the tarball and install Java

     ```
     tar zxvf jre-7u7-linux-i586.tar.gz
     ```

   The Java files are installed in a directory called jre1.7.0_07 in the current directory. 
   In this example, it is installed in the /usr/java/jre1.7.0_07 directory.
   Delete the .tar.gz file if you want to save disk space.

Comment: I had to do it 3 or 4 times .. but this worked

Comment: nice help, but 'Unpack the tarball and install Java': how to install Java?

Comment: This worked in Ubuntu/Kubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Since licence changes by Oracle, the latest Sun/Java environment is not available in the repositories anymore.

The team of webup8.org has made a nice workaround in the own repositories. You will get autmatic updates with it! I use it on my own and always have the latest version:

[1] http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Otherwise, have a look at the Community help for other workarounds:

[2] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Oracle_Java_7

Comment: I totally advocate webupd8's ppa. There are also many other convenient things in it. Here is an overview: [WebUpd8 PPA Overview](http://ppa.webupd8.org/ppas)

Answer (score 0):

1 - Open **Terminal**

2 - Copy & Paste Command:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

3 - Press **Enter**

4 - Enter Your Username

5 - Press Enter

The Java Plugin Will Now Be Installed.

In Chrome go to Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Privacy then click on

Content Settings > Plug-ins then click on Disable Individual Plug-in

**Disable both IceTea-Web Plugin and Java(TM)**

Restart the browser.

Chrome > Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Privacy then click on

Content Settings > Plug-ins then click on **Disable Individual Plug-in**

**Enable only IceTea-Web Plugin**

Check That The Browser Plugin Works Correctly By Going To The Java Site:

http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre

Comment: Already donde that several times. It doesn't update. I also tried deleting some files in the profile folder so it will look for the other plug-ins but it still doesn't update.

Comment: tried your edit ... it does even less now ... now it says that it could not load the icedtea web plugin